# Alternatives to CKEditor for WSYIWYG text area editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wysiwyg

Me and my company are looking for an alternative to CKEditor to use in our CMS. Preferably we would like something a bit more up to date and significantly more lightweight.

We're a rails 3.2 shop, so something that integrates easily with rails would be nice.

Really we are just looking for the formatting features, and possibly image uploading (though we have an api, so this might be difficult) via integration with paperclip.

So far we've seen

- CKEditor
- TinyMCE
- Markdown

Does anyone have any suggestions or thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I like TinyMCE personally- pretty straightforward to implement and there are even some gems. https://github.com/mikehoward/use_tinymce

Comment: Or there's also 37signals take- https://github.com/37signals/wysihat

Comment: This is very constructive actually.

Comment: Here are two more: http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/ https://github.com/tholman/zenpen

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just found:

http://redactorjs.com/

http://aloha-editor.org/

https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5

http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

Update (this one is pretty great and customizable): 
https://github.com/guardian/scribe

Comment: Some good options, both free and paid. As for paid, redactor is seeming quite nice.

Comment: [Raptor Editor](https://www.raptor-editor.com/) is great (as per @eduludi's answer). Full disclosure: I made it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try these: [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/)

[Xstandard](http://xstandard.com/)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a WYSIWYG editor for a Rails 3.2 project, take a look at **[Mercury Editor](http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/)**.
There is also a [Railscast (#296)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor) that explains how it works.

**[Raptor Editor](http://www.raptor-editor.com/)** is another awesome option.

For a tiny alternative, I suggest **[CLEditor](https://github.com/cleditor/cleditor)** (but seem to be "abandoned" at this time)

Answer (score -1):

Try CLEEDITOR

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/CLEditor