# OpenCart removes line breaks from description

Tags: opencart

I have a Opencart site that has free and paid code packages.  I have been trying to find where in the code it is removing my line breaks.  If you enter code into the text editor it saves the line breaks into the database.

When you go to edit the product it has removed all the line breaks when the page loads.  Does anyone know where this can be fixed.  My first thought is the WYSIWYG editor but I am lost on how to prevent this from happening.

Anyone know what file is causing this glitch.

Edit: If we cant fix the editor does anyone know what file contains the form for adding/editing a product so i can remove the id and just use the textarea

Comment: I have never heard of similar problem. True is that some WYSIWYGs try to "repair" the broken HTML markup and they usually remove empty lines and break-lines in that HTML markup. If this is Your case (even if You input only a plain text - usually it is then wrapped up by `<p>` or `<div>` element) try to use HTML break-lines, thus `<br>` or `<br />` (depending on Your HTML's DTD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard of this problem before... it is caused by ckeditor... you can remove ckeditor and paste raw html into the text area if you like... alternatively you could use a separate WYSIWYG editor such as tinymce or similar... look here for a few options http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/ or here [Alternatives to CKEditor for WSYIWYG text area editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719241/alternatives-to-ckeditor-for-wsyiwyg-text-area-editor)

Contact me if you need help installing any of them